# Relative phase of a qubit

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is it possible to choose a suitable basis for a qubit so that the relative phase can be changed arbitrarily? In other words, do there exist rotation operators that can take a qubit with a specific relative phase to another relative phase?

Comment: $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\0& e^{\imath \phi} \end{array} \right) $?

Comment: Any rotation operator whose axis is aligned with the spin axis will do this.